# Is the wind mentioned in Stinking Cloud generated by the spell, or does it tell the reader when a wind of that magnitude can dispel the cloud?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

> A moderate wind (at least 10 miles per hour) disperses the cloud after 4 rounds. A strong wind (at least 20 miles per hour) disperses it after 1 round.

I would assume that it refers to the strength of any wind that might come along (such as from *gust of wind* and could disperse it. But in that case, there should be a *can* somewhere in there; ie:

> A moderate wind (at least 10 miles per hour) *can* disperse the cloud...

The way it's written makes it sound like a strong wind emerges after a round and blows the cloud away; in that case it might as well be an instantaneous effect rather than 1-minute concentration spell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It informs the reader of how quickly a wind *can* disperse the cloud

We can see from the spell description that Stinking Cloud has a duration of one minute (with concentration), and that

> You create a 20-foot-radius sphere of yellow, nauseating gas centered on a point within range. The cloud spreads around corners, and its area is heavily obscured. *The cloud lingers in the air for the duration.*

(Emphasis added)

If a wind of that type appeared *by default*, it seems unlikely that it would be dispersed twice, or that the winds would be mentioned in that order.

Comment: That's how I assumed it worked. It'd make sense. The "can" omission seems odd, but the declaration of lingering probably overrules it. Thank you!

Comment: You're right that it's a bit of a confusing way of wording it, but as far as I can see you made the right call.

Comment: Actually, I think the missing word is “would” - “can” implies such a wind might optionally disperse it.